# how to get value from a string using regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

this is my string

```
$string = "<table><tr><td><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01IG6C0D4" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ltpJWi8jL._SL160_.jpg" alt="Product Image" style='border:0'/></a></td><td><tr><td>List Price <strike>$17.99</strike></td></tr><tr><td><b>Deal Price: $11.04</b></td></tr><tr><td>You Save: $6.95 (39%)</td></tr><tr><td>Save on the AmazonBasics Foldable Laundry Hamper</td></tr><tr><td>Expires Apr 28, 2017</td></tr></td></tr>";
```

please help me to extract the 39% (it ca be changed) from this string using regular expression in PHP.
I am weak in the regular expression.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `preg_match()` function to match the pattern `\d{1,}\s*%` means one or more digits (0-9) followed by space or not and finally followed by `%` signal.

`preg_match()` return if the pattern was matched or not, in case of positive the string (captured) will be store in the third argument (`$m`).

```
$string = '<table><tr><td><a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IG6C0D4" target="_blank"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ltpJWi8jL._SL160_.jpg" alt="Product Image" style=border:0/></a></td><td><tr><td>List Price <strike>$17.99</strike></td></tr><tr><td><b>Deal Price: $11.04</b></td></tr><tr><td>You Save: $6.95 (**39%**)</td></tr><tr><td>Save on the AmazonBasics Foldable Laundry Hamper</td></tr><tr><td>Expires Apr 28, 2017</td></tr></td></tr>';
preg_match('/\d{1,}\s*%/', $string, $m);
```

To capture a number with a fraction this regex `(\d{1,}|\d{1,}\.\d{1,})\s*%` sounds better

```
$string = 'asdasd 36.45%';
echo preg_match('/(\d{1,}|\d{1,}\.\d{1,})\s*%/', $string, $m);
```

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the following regex (one or more digits followed by a % sign) I am able to get the match:

```
(\d+)\%
```

Example - https://regex101.com/r/a36Zdl/1

Comment: Thanks for help :)